# MVC Razor views have no Intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

I'm on MVC 5, .NET 4.6, Visual Studio Professional 2015. I occasionally get a problem where VS decides it doesn't want to see certain references anymore. It's usually the ones directly related to MVC. The current issue is `The type 'WebViewPage<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`

This problem has been resolved in the past by uninstalling/reinstalling the MVC NuGet package, but that did not work this time. I've tried all of the following, nothing has worked. The project compiles and runs with no problems, it's only Intellisense that has a problem. Each of these steps was done with all views closed, they were reopened afterward. Each was also tested a second time closing VS in between.

- Ensure that `System.Web.Mvc` is actually referenced and found (no yellow exclamation mark in the references list).
- Uninstall/reinstall MVC.
- Ensure that `System.Web.Mvc` is referenced in both `Web.config` files (Views folder and root level), and that those references have the correct version `5.0.0.0` and the right `PublicKeyToken`.
- Ensure the reference is set to `Copy Local` and is in fact being copied when the project is built.
- Delete **all** files from the `bin` and `obj` folders in each project in the solution.
- Ensure all projects in the solution are targeting the same version of .NET (4.6).

I have so many problems with Visual Studio package management.... How can I fix VS supposedly not finding the reference in views so that Intellisense works again?

Comment: Try this: http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008

Comment: does this happen after updating MVC version of an old project?

Comment: this is something to do with the config files - You can see in the Error Message it is asking for version 5.2.3.0 but you said that config files has the correct version of 5.0.0.0 you will have to update this to the version 5.2.3.0 in the config files

Comment: @DawoodAwan This did not happen after an upgrade, it arbitrarily happens when I reopen VS after having shut it down for the night. I'm trying using 5.2.3.0 now, but my research in the past has said you need 5.0.0.0. MVC uses that to refer to all versions in the 5.x branch. EF is the same, 6.0.0.0 is used even though the current version is 6.1.x.

Comment: I don't think that's the case for Web.MVC as if you create a new project the config file has 5.2.3.0

Comment: My issue was resolved when I read your first inclination to reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.MVC NuGet package.  I just installed a version below the current, saw that resolved it, then updated to the latest.  Now I'm as good as new.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Error Message it is saying that it can't find `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0` and then you mentioned that the config files are `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0`

So first try updating all `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0` to `Version=5.2.3.0` in both **web.config** and **Views config** files

[There is one reference to the library at the end of the views config file :-)]

> If that doesn't work then Try This:

**Make a backup of you config files first -**

I had a similar issue after updating a project from MVC4 to MVC5.

The thing is that the update did not update the config files correctly.

You can create a New MVC Project with latest version and copy the config files from the new Project.

You can copy the  `<runtime>` section, from the `Web.config` file.

And just copy the Whole of the `Views config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <!--Then copy over your View References-->

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```